# Incoming Email on Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-designer

Does anyone know if it is possible to configure incoming email for a sharepoint list with sharepoint being on prem but our email server being hosted on O365?  I have outgoing configured, but not having any luck with incoming.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following link?

http://blog.bonzai-intranet.com/analysthq/2014/07/sending-email-from-sharepoint-on-premises-via-office-365/

As an additional recommendation, I would add a scheduled task on the server that checks that the SMTP service is actually running (example: once every hour). Let me know if you need help with that.

With regards to the incoming email, you need to be careful if you have a DNS zone which is the same as your Office 365 domains example "test.com". Ideally you should offload these DNS zone/s to an external DNS server to avoid issues or use forwarding since the local domain will always be preferred.

If you still don't manage, please provide additional feedback about what exactly you are doing and/or experiencing.